# Laravel insert with ajax returning error 500

Tags: php, laravel

I am very new to laravel but this should be a fairly simple task. However I'm getting an error.

This is my migration:

```
Schema::create('tblloanapp', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->integer('BR_ID');
        $table->integer('ClientID');
        $table->integer('ClientChkID');
        $table->integer('LoanType');
        $table->integer('LoanPurpose');
        $table->string('Principal');
        $table->integer('Term');
        $table->integer('PaymentMode');
        $table->double('INT_RATE');
        $table->double('PEN_RATE');
        $table->string('OL_TEMP_APP_NO');
        $table->string('APPLICATION_NO')->nullable();
        $table->integer('LoanStatus');
        $table->dateTime('DateRequested');
        $table->dateTime('DateApproved')->nullable();
        $table->text('ClientRemarks')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

And this is my insert code:

```
ApplicationForm::insert([
            'BR_ID' => $BR_ID,
            'ClientID' => $clientID,
            'ClientChkID' => $clientChkID,
            'LoanType' => $loanType,
            'LoanPurpose' => $loanPurpose,
            'Principal' => $principal,
            'Term' => $term,
            'PaymentMode' => $paymentMode,
            'INT_RATE' => $interest,
            'PEN_RATE' => $penalty,
            'OL_TEMP_APP_NO' => $tempAppNo,
            'APPLICATION_NO' => "",
            'LoanStatus' => 1,
            'DateRequested' => $datetime,
            'DateApproved' => "",
            'ClientRemarks' => $clientRemarks
        ]);
```

Most of these values are from variables that get their value from form data

I get the error

> jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/application_form 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

This is my model:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ApplicationForm extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'tblloanapp';
}
```

If it helps, the method that gets data from the database within the same class is working. This method is returning an error so I guess it's not a database connection issue.

Comment: Can you wrap your data array with another array "[[]]", as insert function is used for mass insertion.? else, use "create" function instead

Comment: Have you checked your log file? /storage/logs/laravel-todaysdate.log Alternatively if you're using Chrome (although most/all browsers have something similar) you can open your developer tools and use the "Network" tab to inspect the ajax request and it should preview the response which should have the error stack trace in it.

Comment: @TimSheehan I was able to solve my error because of this. Thank you, I did not know you could actually do that.

Comment: The error was #1. The interest rates contained % sign so I used floatval to convert them and truncate the %. #2. The date format was incorrect for datetime data type.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without the stack trace exception. But I guess that your problem is that your attributes are guarded. 
You should add following attributes on your ApplicationForm model :

```
protected $guarded = [];
```

Comment: I've tried adding it and still no luck.Yes the stack trace exception would be helpful. But Ajax just returns the response from the server which is error 500. Is there anyway I could view it with ajax? Sorry, I am very new to Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

use `create` function instead

```
ApplicationForm::create([
            // key => value
        ]);
```

Comment: How would using this change things? Without explanation this is basically a code only answer. It doesn't explain how to use it or why it works, or how to tell if it worked.